# Show that if a sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ converges to $a$, then so does the sequence of greatest lower bounds of subsets of $\langle a_n\rangle$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

I'm attempting to prove the following theorem.

**Theorem.** Let $\langle a_n \rangle$ be some arbitrary, bounded sequence, and let $A_n$ denote the set $\{a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \ldots\}$. Suppose $\langle a_n \rangle$ converges to some $a$, and let $\langle G_n \rangle$ be a sequence where the $G_n^{th}$ term gives the greatest lower bound of the set $A_n$. Show that $\langle G_n \rangle$ converges to $a$ as well.

Note it can be shown that $\langle G_n \rangle$ is increasing and convergent to $lub(\langle G_n \rangle)$ (where $lub(A)$/$lub\{A\}$ denotes the *least upper bound* of $A$ (this follows from the fact that a bounded, increasing monotonic sequence is convergent to its least upper bound).

**Attempt.** Suppose that $\langle a_n \rangle$ converges to $a$. Then, for all real $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n\geq N$:

$$-\epsilon < a_n - a < \epsilon$$

Further, it is clear that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$G_n \leq a_n$$

...for $\langle G_n \rangle$ is the greatest lower bound of the set $\{a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \ldots \}$.

Hence, for $n$ at least $N$:

$$G_n - a \leq a_n - a < \epsilon$$

Since $\langle G_n \rangle$ converges to $lub\{\langle G_n \rangle\}$, we know also that, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n\geq M$:

$$-\epsilon < G_n - lub\{\langle G_n \rangle \} < \epsilon$$

It is clear that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$G_n - lub\{\langle G_n \rangle \} \leq G_n -a$$

For otherwise:

$$G_n - lub\{\langle G_n \rangle \} > G_n -a \textrm{  } \Rightarrow \textrm{  } - lub\{\langle G_n \rangle \} > -a \textrm{  } \Rightarrow \textrm{  } lub\{\langle G_n \rangle \} < a$$

---

...here's where I'm stuck. I had in mind an argument for why the last line leads to a contradiction (or alternatively why $lub\{\langle G_g \rangle \}$ must be $a$), but I've forgotten it (if it was even valid).

Am I headed in the right direction? How may I proceed?

Comment: One useful property that students often fail to use directly, but can save a lot of work, is that a real sequence $(a_n)_n$ converges to $a$ iff  $\{n: a_n\not\in (a-r,\,a+r)\}$ is a finite set for any $r>0.$ BTW, many different books use many different notations for denoting sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the fact that $G_n$ is a lower bound of $A_n$. Since not necessarily all sequence of lower bounds of $A_n$ converge to $a$, you should somehow use the fact that $G_n$ is the 'greatest' lower bound of $A_n$.

For each $n\ge N$, since $G_n$ is the greatest lower bound of $A_n$, there is some $m\ge n$, s.t $G_n \le a_m\le G_n+\varepsilon$. Since $a-\varepsilon < a_n < a+\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$, we have $$a-2\varepsilon<a_n-\varepsilon\le G_n\le a_n<a+\varepsilon.$$ Since this holds for all $n\ge N$, by definition of limit we have shown that $G_n\to a$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you’re already done. You’ve shown $G_n-a<\epsilon$ and $-\epsilon<G_n-a$. Hence $|G_n-a|<\epsilon$ and since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, $G_n\to a$.

Answer (score 0):

The part up to

> $$G_n - a \leq a_n - a < \epsilon$$

I find it correct.

(What comes after I apologize but I don’t understand it. Might be correct-I just can’t confirm. For now I’ll focus to finish with convergence of greatest lower bounds sequence)

I would have avoided working with $G_n$-notation from start since the greatest lower bound is the infimum of a set:
$$G_n=inf(A_n)$$

Next I would add the context of convergence of original sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ to the definition of greatest lower bound:

$$\left.\begin{align}\forall n \ge N, N=N(\epsilon),a-\epsilon &\lt a_n\\ inf(A_n)&\le a_i, \forall i \ge N\end{align}\right\}\Rightarrow a-\epsilon \lt inf(A_n)$$

The reason for this result is that the greatest lower bound-the infimum of a set has to be the number second (or equal) to the least number in the set, therefore located in the gap between that number and the lesser value $a-\epsilon$.

The two results combined lead to the convergence of greatest lower bound sequence:
$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N=N(\epsilon): (n\ge N\Rightarrow |a_n-a|\lt  \epsilon) \Rightarrow (a-\epsilon \lt inf(A_n)\lt a+\epsilon)$$

Now regarding the least upper bounds: in a similar fashion, that sequence also converges to a. The two sequences converge to the same value, the greatest lower bound being always lesser than the least upper bounds:
$$a-\epsilon\lt inf(A_n)\lt sup(A_n)\lt a+\epsilon$$